# How to login with only email and password in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Plugin Name: WooCommerce

plugins\woocommerce\templates\global\form-login.php

```
<label for="username"><?php _e( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
```

It display email instead of username or email which i wanted

includes\class-wc-form-handler.php

```
if ( empty( $username ) ) {
    throw new Exception( '<strong>' . __( 'Error:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . __( 'Email is required.', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
```

It display validation for email correct but it login with username also

I want it to login only with email and password before checkout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you look closely  at
>   `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php` at
>   line num 878 there is a filter
>   [`woocommerce_process_login_errors`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_process_login_errors/), which accepts validations
>   error, username and password. So you can overwrite this by this filter
>   help.

Here is the code:

```
// define the woocommerce_process_login_errors callback 
function filter_woocommerce_process_login_errors($validation_error, $post_username, $post_password)
{
    //if (strpos($post_username, '@') == FALSE)
    if (!filter_var($post_username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //<--recommend option
    {
        throw new Exception( '<strong>' . __( 'Error', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . __( 'Please Enter a Valid Email ID.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $validation_error;
}

// add the filter 
add_filter('woocommerce_process_login_errors', 'filter_woocommerce_process_login_errors', 10, 3);
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.** *in WooCommerce 2.6.X*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankew 4 ur help :) @Raunak Gupta.